# SQL to return user list with the picture count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**user**

- id_user
- name

**user_picture**

- id_picture
- id_user
- filename

This returns all rows:

```
SELECT u.id_user AS id, u.name FROM user AS u
```

This is supposed to return all users with their picture count, but it only returns 1 row of the users table:

```
SELECT u.id_user AS id, u.name, COUNT(p.id_user_picture) AS pics FROM user AS u LEFT JOIN user_picture AS p ON p.id_user = u.id_user
```

I need it to return something like this:

- **id_user**, **name**, **pics**
- 1, Andres, 14
- 2, Cecilia, 7
- 3, John, 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must group the field then the COUNT function will count each value for each grouped field.

Try with this:

```sql
SELECT u.id_user AS id, u.name, COUNT(p.id_user_picture) AS pics 
    FROM user AS u 
    LEFT JOIN user_picture AS p ON p.id_user = u.id_user
    GROUP BY u.id_user, u.name;
```

Comment: `, u.name` is unnecessary (`join` is filtering it), but +1 for complete answer

Comment: @jaczes why is u.name unnecessary?

Comment: @andufo because mysql don't have strict control about grouping fields, but it is a good practice for SQL standards.

Answer (score 0):

you need group by

```
     GROUP BY u.id_user
```